# Может ли бы middleware асинхронным в ExpressJs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Есть зада создать таблицы в бд, если их не существует. Я придумал два способа:

1. Создать middleware(он асинхронный т.к запрос к бд), где описана вся логика.
2. Создать отдельный роут и в комоненте App(React) вызвать useEffect где делать запрос к этому роуту. Логика такая же как в middleware.

Подскажите пожалуйста как из этих способов более правильный.

Comment: Может конечно. MW в Express заканчивает свою работу вызовом функции `next` (третьего параметра)

Comment: да, на счет next() знаю) Просто нигде не нагулил за асинхронные middleware, поэтому решил уточнить. Спасибо

Comment: `asyncFunction().then(() => next())`